# Ruby/Gem/Bundler Caching my local gem files

Tags: ruby, rubygems, bundler

I'm working on a gem locally, referenced it using bundle config local.GEMNAME (this is confirmed by the printout of bundle install).  However, unless I bump the version on the gem, I can't use the most up-to-date code.  When errors occur in the old code, it references the file in the right place, where I have fixed the error.  I temporarily had bundler-cache-all switched on, but have turned that to false (and deleted .bundle/config).

Where is this cache living (I'm on OSX, using RBenv and ruby 2.1.2), and how can I turn it off?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried running `spring stop` and restarting your server (assuming this is a Rails app)?

If it's referencing the file in the right place but executing the wrong code, that indicates that the old code is still loaded into memory. Often, this is because of the Spring pre-loader, which is used by default with Rails 4.1+.